# Updating a table in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, updates

I have a `Customer` table that has 55 million records. I need to update a column `HHPK` with increment values

Example:

```
12345....upto 55 million
```

I'm using the following script but the script is erroring out with transaction log for the database is getting full..

DB is using simple recovery model

```
DECLARE @SEQ BIGINT 
SET @SEQ = 0
UPDATE Customers 
SET @SEQ = HHPK = @SEQ + 1
```

Is there any other way to do that task? Please help

Comment: Table already has identity column CustomerPK. How do i Update HHPK to be same as CustomerPK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your table already has a `CustomerPK` identity column, just use:

```
UPDATE dbo.Customers
SET HHPK = CustomerPK
```

Of course - with 55 million rows, this will be a strain on your log file. So you might want to do this in batches - preferably of less than 5000 rows to avoid *lock escalation* effects that would exclusively lock the entire table:

```
UPDATE TOP (4500) dbo.Customers
SET HHPK = CustomerPK
WHERE HHPK IS NULL
```

and repeat this until the entire table has been updated.

But really: if you already **have** an `INT IDENTITY` column `CustomerPK` - why do you need a second column to hold the same values? Doesn't make a lot of sense to me ....